# Is there a way to remove comma/s in my database? Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How can I remove comma(s) from my database?

I need to remove them per data.
So I have this data

`Product 1,Product 2,,,,,`  - I need to remove per commas

So, I need to remove per commas. Here is my View

```
<?php echo form_open('subjects/remove_core'); ?>

 <?php  $core_subjs = explode(',', $subjects['core_subjects']); ?>
    <?php foreach($core_subjs as $key => $subject): ?>

        <input type="hidden" name="remove_core" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $subjects['core_subjects'].'' ?>" /><br>

        <input type="text" name="coresubjs[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $subject ?>" /><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Save</button>

  <?php endforeach ?>
</form>
```

My Controller

```
public function remove_core(){

    $this->subject_model->remove_core();

    redirect('subjects/edit/'.$_SESSION['editID']);
}
```

My Model- So in here I am not sure if I am doing this right, as per result is not correct.

```
public function remove_core(){
        $data = array(
            'core_subjects' => " "
        );

        $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('coresubjID'));
        return $this->db->update('subjects', $data);
}
```

How I implode data

```
public function update_core(){
        $data = array(
            'core_subjects' => implode(',',$this->input->post('coresubjs[]'))
        );

        $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('coresubjID'));
        return $this->db->update('subjects', $data);
}
```

Comment: What you are imploding? are you imploding and insert into database?what is the source of imploded data?

Comment: @Hardood - in my database, data are imploded. what I need is to remove the comma(s) from the database. I am asking for the query

Comment: @Harood - check my upated question, please disregard the implode part

Comment: What the origin of imploded data please? i want to help to prevent inserting a such data again in your db

Comment: In either php use `rtrim($subjects['core_subjects'], ',');` or mysql use `TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM core_subject) AS core_subject` which will remove all extraneous trailing commas.

Comment: @Hardood - hello sir, please kindly check my updated question for the implode part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the extraneous commas going into the database, you can use `array_filter`, `trim`, or `preg_replace` depending on your preference.

With a theoretical value for `$this->input->post('coresubjs[]')` of

```php
array(
   '',
   '',
   '0',
   'A',
   'B',
   '',
   'D',
   '',
   '',
);
```

Using `implode(',')` only will result in

```
,,0,A,B,,D,,
```

### Disclaimer

However please keep in mind, that any commas in the post values will not be properly accounted for and should be escaped using another means. eg: `1,000` will be exploded as `array("1", "000")`. For this reason I recommend refactoring in favor of using `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` or `serialize()` and `unserialize()`, instead of `implode(',')` and `explode(',')`

Example: https://3v4l.org/I2ObY

---

### [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Removes the "empty" values (`0, "", false, null`) from the `implode` array argument.
This will work against any input value that is empty, including the middle of the array.

```php
implode(',', array_filter($this->input->post('coresubjs[]')))
```

**Result**
*Notice that all extraneous commas and the `0` value was removed*

```
A,B,D
```

To circumvent the issue with "empty" values such as `0, false`, you can use a custom callback instead.

```php
implode(',', array_filter($this->input->post('coresubjs[]'), function($value) {
    return null !== $value && '' !== $value;
}))
```

**Result**
*Notice all extraneous commas were removed*

```
0,A,B,D
```

---

### [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Removes only the leading and trailing commas from the `implode` value.

```php
trim(implode(',', $this->input->post('coresubjs[]')), ',')
```

**Result**
*Notice the leading and trailing commas are removed but extra comma in the middle remained.*

```
0,A,B,,D
```

---

### [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Similar to `trim`, removing the leading and trailing commas from the `implode` value, with the addition of replacing any 2 or more commas in the middle with a single comma.

```php
preg_replace(['/,{2,}/', '/^,+/', '/,+$/'], [',', '', ''], implode(',', $this->input->post('coresubjs[]')))
```

Pattern Explanation:

- `,{2,}` any 2 or more commas
- `^,+` begins with 1 or more comma
- `,+$` ends with 1 ore more comma

**Result**
*Notice All extraneous commas have been removed*

```
0,A,B,D
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `update_core function`, you need to `trim` the additional `','`. You can do this as follow -

```
public function update_core(){
        $data = array(
            'core_subjects' => rtrim(implode(',', $this->input->post('coresubjs[]')), ','); // remove the extra ',' to the right
        );

        $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('coresubjID'));
        return $this->db->update('subjects', $data);
}
```

Also, remember that you don't have to remove the data every time you update. When updating it will automatically overwrite the previous value. So your `remove_core` method is redundant and should be removed

Comment: hello i've tried your code, but the data and the comma still hasn't been removed. thank you for your response sir

Comment: can you `print_r($data['core_subjects'])` and share the output?

Comment: I've tried this - `rtrim(implode(' ', $this->input->post('coresubjs[]')), ',');` but the problem is the all commas have been removed

Comment: Is there a possibility where i can remove 1 comme per textbox? thank you good sir

Comment: your code works, but the problem is that all commas are removed when i clicked the submit button

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: o my bad :( , i haven't cleared my question :( what I really means is that to only remove 1 per comma .

Comment: hello good sir, I have updated my question. please consider my mistake, thank you

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Because what you're saying and what you're doing in your code is totally different.

Comment: can you give me at least a pseudo code how can I achieve to remove 1 comma per textbox ? thanks

Comment: So, are you saying that every value has 1 extra comma like `first value = 'english', second value = 'maths',` and you want to remove this extra comma? Is this what you're saying?

Comment: so if I would like to remove the second value `maths` then the first valie `english` should not be removed

Comment: so is there any possiblity i can achieve it?

Comment: Ok, so the first thing you're doing wrong is that there is only one form for multiple fields, every time you click on it, it submits the form with all the values.

Comment: So you can either make multiple forms per text box or make an ajax call on button click

Comment: after doing so, in the controller, get all the values, explode them(get them in an array), find the value, remove that value, then implode it and then save it in a database. Gotta say, not a good way of storing values. What you could do is make a separate table for all this and use join to show and delete values.

Comment: done, already done that, now I gotta delete some of them, how can i delete specific data so the comma will then be removed?

Comment: See my previous comment. after doing that you shouldn't have a problem of extra `','`